# Proving that the ring $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle{p}\rangle$ is a field with $p^2$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Can someone help me with this problem?

Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a prime of the form $4k+3$. Prove that the ring 
$\mathbb Z[i]/\langle{p}\rangle$ is a field with $p^2$ elements.

Comment: First step, do you know what it is?  What do its elements look like?

Comment: Second step: why must it be a field?

Comment: A key step: Why is it necessary that $p$ be of the form $4k+3$? Hint: when $p=5$ we get $(2+i)(2-i)=5=0$ because $2^2+1^2\equiv0\pmod 5$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : You can show that : $$\mathbb Z[i]/\langle{p}\rangle \cong\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1,p\rangle\cong (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[i]$$

Comment: And also, you need to think of a famous result about when $-1$ has a square root mod $p$

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Why is it a field? Notice that $2=1+1$ and every number that is $1\pmod{4}$ is the sum of two squares. If $p=2$ or if $p=4k+1$ then the conclusion is false!

**Step 2:** Prove it has at most $p^2$ elements, because every number in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is equivalent to a number in the set $S:=\{a+bi:a,b\in\{0,1,\ldots, p-1\}\}$.

**Step 3:** Show that no two elements of $S$ get mapped to the same place by the map $\varphi:x\to x +\langle p\rangle$, which means that every element of $S$ is a unique element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle p\rangle$, and so that set has at least $p^2$ elements.

Thus it follows that it is a field with exactly $p^2$ elements.

If any of these steps prove problematic, do comment with what you've tried and I'll give you some advice.